# how to bind to items within an observable array in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following observable array:

```
self.Profiles =ko.observableArray( ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData, function (profile) {
                return {
                    StartDate : formatDateOnly(profile.StartDate),
                    EndDate : formatDateOnly(profile.EndDate),
                    ProfileID :profile.ID,
                    ProfileName : profile.Name,
                    ProjectName : profile.ProjectName,
                    ReadingListID : profile.ReadingListID,
                    ReadingListName : profile.ReadingListName

                };
            }));
```

I want to bind a dropdown to the profiles to show the profile names, if the value of the drop down changes then I want to update span elements with the new corresponding values to the selected profileID.

```
<table id="readingListApplyToProfile" class="fullWidthTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Profile:
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboProfile" name="cboProfile" data-bind="options: Profiles, optionsText: 'ProfileName', 'optionsCaption': 'Select profile...', optionsValue:'ProfileID'"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                End Date:
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="'text':EndDate"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I cannot get the spans to update because the span elements are unaware of the dropdowns value, can anyone help me please. I am totally lost.

Comment: Maybe it would work to bind the select's value to a computedObservable that takes in a ProfileID and outputs the ProfileName of the correct Profile, and then bind the spans' text to the same computedObservable

Comment: that probably would work but I dont want to do the same code for all the properties, Im hoping someone could show me a better solution. thanks

Comment: Makes sense. This is a complete guess because I'm not so good at computedObservables, but would it be possible to output the whole Profile object, and bind to a specific property on the span? Like `data-bind="text: getProfile.ProfileName"` or something like that?

Comment: How many such drop downs do you have? Is this just a single drop down and a span?

Comment: yes, its a single dropdown

Comment: @jonhopkins im afraid that wouldnt work.

Comment: I didn't think so either. But somehow it did. See my answer

Comment: @johnhopkins. You don't need a computed observable for this. You only need just an observable. Set the value of the drop down to that and bind the span to this observable. Check my answer!

Comment: @SujeshArukil The way your answer works, the span can only contain the id of the selected Profile, or whatever xerxes chooses to bind as the value of the options. With the computedObservable returning the whole object, it's possible to have one select and many spans, each bound to a different property of the selected profile.

Comment: Ah! did not read the question right. Yes. a computed would do, but I would do it slightly different. Can I update your fiddle?

Comment: Of course. If I learn from it, I don't mind others' input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/fgZNQ/4/ simple change. Still using a computed, but a read only. check it out.

Comment: Very nice. If you don't mind, I'd like to add your version to my answer. Also +1 for a much better version than I have haha

Comment: sure man! We were on the same page. You put some, I put some and we help together :D.. Good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is a value binding on the drop down list. Here is a fiddle I created.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/sBZvb/1/

```
<select id="cboProfile" name="cboProfile" data-bind="options: Profiles, optionsText: 'ProfileName', 'optionsCaption': 'Select profile...', optionsValue:'ProfileID', value: selectedProfileId ">
```

And here is the viewmodel

```
var myViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
        this.Profiles =ko.observableArray([{
                    StartDate : '02/01/2012',
                    EndDate : '01/01/2013',
                    ProfileID :10,
                    ProfileName : 'Some Name',
                    ProjectName : 'Some Project',
                    ReadingListID : 100,
                    ReadingListName : 'Some List',
                },
                {
                    StartDate : '12/01/2012',
                    EndDate : '02/27/2013',
                    ProfileID :12,
                    ProfileName : 'New Name',
                    ProjectName : 'New Project',
                    ReadingListID : 200,
                }]);
    this.selectedProfileId = ko.observable({}); //this stores the selected id

}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

Hope that helps.

Suj

Answer (score 2):

I had the idea of a computedObservable that takes in a ProfileID and outputs the Profile corresponding to that ID, and then binding the spans to the various properties of the outputted object. Surprisingly, it worked. I was messing around with Sujesh Arukil's fiddle to try my idea so the model is very similar.

Working example showing multiple spans: http://jsfiddle.net/jonhopkins/fgZNQ/2/

The Model:

```
var myViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
        self.Profiles =ko.observableArray([{
                    StartDate : '02/01/2012',
                    EndDate : '01/01/2013',
                    ProfileID :10,
                    ProfileName : 'Some Name',
                    ProjectName : 'Some Project',
                    ReadingListID : 100,
                    ReadingListName : 'Some List',
                },
                {
                    StartDate : '12/01/2012',
                    EndDate : '02/27/2013',
                    ProfileID :12,
                    ProfileName : 'New Name',
                    ProjectName : 'New Project',
                    ReadingListID : 200,
                }]);

    self.selectedProfileId = ko.observable();

    self.getProfile = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.Profiles().length; i++) {
                if (self.Profiles()[i].ProfileID == self.selectedProfileId()) {
                    return self.Profiles()[i];
                }
            }
            // in case there was no match, output a blank Profile
            return [{
                    StartDate : '',
                    EndDate : '',
                    ProfileID : '',
                    ProfileName : '',
                    ProjectName : '',
                    ReadingListID : '',
                    ReadingListName : ''
            }];
        },
        write: function(value) {
            self.selectedProfileId(value);
        },
        owner: self
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

**EDIT:** Sujesh suggested a much better version of the computedObservable.

```
self.getProfile = ko.computed(function(){
    var profile = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Profiles(), function(prof){
        return prof.ProfileID == self.selectedProfileId();
    });

    return profile || {};
});
```

The HTML:

```
<table id="readingListApplyToProfile" class="fullWidthTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Profile:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="cboProfile" name="cboProfile" data-bind="options: Profiles, optionsText: 'ProfileName', 'optionsCaption': 'Select profile...', optionsValue:'ProfileID', value: getProfile "></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            End Date:
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: getProfile().ProfileName"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```